# Overflow scroll doesn't work with elements positioned with absolute

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, css-position, chatroom

I'm trying to make a kind of chat room. When new messages come, previous messages move up and dissappears when they leave the div.

I want to make the div scrollable to see previous messages but `overflow: scroll` doesn't work.

I tried to set elements to position:relative instead of absolute but then the elements position themselves chaotically.

This is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lgq1zfa/1/

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code but there was no `.ventana` class defined for js or html. However to make scrolling work on absolute positioned elements you should define width and height so the browser identifies when the overflow happens.

I hope this is what you needed. ;)

Comment: So sorry, I added the wrong link.  I just edited it. Could you test it again please?

Comment: I have width and height setted. But it doesn't work.